# How to get the user to set his location on a mobile app?

Tags: maps, location

Our mobile app helps in getting content based on the Neighborhood that the user has selected. Also, we know that users would like to receive content from more than one Neighborhood. What would be the best way to engage the user to do this step and make it seem effortless?

[image: SignUp 1st page]

[image: Location Selection]

Comment: Please provide more information on what the app does, how and when a user might want to add neighborhoods, etc.  Also mockups of the current design and any way you have thought of for adding this feature would be helpful.  Right now there is not enough information to answer.

Comment: Do you mean actually entering his/her location, or just allowing automatic geolocation?

Comment: @dan1111 - This is a neighborhood app that provides content based on the location that the user has selected. Currently, I am using the sign up process to gather this data. I am still trying to figure out how to to upload the mockups... Will try to do that soon.

Comment: @jcaron - currently using geolocation on a map like Uber would.

Comment: And what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: This is the only way I could think of. I was trying to get this validated and some users skipped this.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution to your problem is to explain why you want to turn on their location sharing setting and how it can benefit them. The way you actually design the interaction can be however you choose, but the core tenant is explaining the reason and benefits for turning their location on.

When your app is turned on, you are able to ask permission to turn their location sharing service on (which can be stored as a default setting after agreeing to the terms).

Comment: Our intention of asking for their location is to send them content based on their location and interests. So the first step is to identify their location and based on the location, show them a list of interests to choose from.

Asking permission is anyway happening. 
What I am unable to predict is - why the users are not willing to share their location?

Comment: Hmm, to identify why they are not is kind of tricky. There are many reasons, such as using the data plan, privacy, etc. One thing you could consider doing is on app load, check if share location is off. If it is, ask them to turn it on, if they say no, then ask them to explain why. This could work if you are adamant on truly understanding why. It could also be a way for you to educate your user that you are trying to help them.

Comment: I think I will try and ask the user to explain why. Thanks